# How to add "Share" action to feed dialog?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, dialog, action, feed

Does anyone know how to make the "Share" option appear next to the "Like" and "Comment" actions in posts generated through the feed dialog?

I can see that the "actions" property might support this, but I don't see any "share" dialog that could be plugged into the link (and the "send" dialog only sends private messages).

What I am looking for is a way to generate a standard Facebook "share" link (with full public/private sharing options) as an "action" property.

Here is our current feed dialog code:

```html
<a href='https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=126736467765&
link=https://apps.facebook.com/karmalyze/?reqtype=action%26actno=$actno&
picture=$post_pict&caption=karmalyze...%20your%20life!&name=$share_act_title&
description=$share_act_description&message=Yummy%20Karma!&
redirect_uri=https://apps.facebook.com/karmalyze/?reqtype=action%26actno=$actno' 
title='Share This'><img class='vmidimage floatright' src='images/icon_kk_fb.png' alt='Like Icon' /></a>
```

I see the "Share" option on many posts. Is this just for posts that Facebook generates, or has someone cracked this code for the rest of us? Thanks!

Comment: Yes that is a Facebook functionality and not available for developers. But Facebook is already providing a similar function, which is you are already using (feed dialog).

Comment: ifaour, does this mean that no third-party app developer has been able to construct this as an "actions" property in their feed dialogs? That would be surprising. I'll keep my eye out for posts that have this.

Answer (score 1):

There is an approach that is messy but will do the job: use the action argument for the feed dialog.

```
function fbShare() {
     //call the API
     var obj = {
        method: 'feed',
        link:  myLink,
        picture: pic, 
        name: myNme,
        caption: myCaption,
        redirect_uri: 'http://facebook.com',
        actions: {"name":"Share","link": url},
        description: myDescription,          
    };

    function callback(response) {
        console.log(response);    
    }

    FB.ui(obj, callback);  
}
```

The actions url should be pretty much the same url as you are showing.

Drawbacks: you aren't given the option to post to someone else's wall and the redirect_uri, which must be present, winds up taking the user away from their wall.

Comment: Brian, I think there's an error in your fbShare() function.

Specifically, you probably meant to close function callback(response) {} after the console.log line, not after FB.ui. That is, the functional structure looks like:

function fbShare() {
  var obj = { 
    ...
  }
  function callback() {
    ...
  }

  FB.ui(..);
}